# Azure WebJobs in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-webjobs

I have an ASP.NET 5 Web Application in Visual Studio 2015 RC.
Now I want to create a WebJob, it can be independently or on the web application. 
There are resources how to do it in .NET 4.6, but how can I deploy an ASP.NET 5 Console Application?
Is there a way to do it like:
https://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do that. Just follow these steps:

1. Create the console app
2. Pack it with the runtime by running `dnu publish --runtime <name of runtime>` (you might to pass `--no-source` too if don't care about having the source code as part of the job).
3. Zip everything in the `bin/output` folder.
4. Upload the zip as a webjob through the Azure Portal.

Caveat: If you want to use CoreCLR, the WebJobs SDK is not available. Nor is the Storage SDK.

PS: There is no tooling support in VS, yet, for the steps above.

Comment: How can I run dnu? Command line doesn't recognize it, what path should be set?

Comment: Install `dnvm` by following the instructions [here](https://github.com/aspnet/home/#upgrading-dnvm-or-running-without-visual-studio) and then run `dnvm upgrade`

Comment: Just wanted to inform that I made it according to above points and it works like a charm.

Comment: @ alek kowalczyk  .Thank you for the post! How did you access the Azure storage objects(blob/queue/table) without the SDKs or in other words how did the .netcore (asp.net 5) console app work with those? Am I missing something here.

Comment: My project.json looks like this -> does this have to be like this? "frameworks": {
      "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": { "Microsoft.Azure.Jobs": "0.3.2-beta" }
    }
  },
  "dnxcore50": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
      "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
      "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
      "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
      "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.2",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
    }
  }
}